# Need help deciphering rabbitmq error messages when trying to connect using Python clinet

Tags: rabbitmq

I have inherited a windows Python application that communicates with linux RabbitMQ.  I need it to connect via SSL, but am currently failing.

I am using [Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.0c](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) [Twisted 10.2.0](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) and [pyOpenSSL](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL/0.10).

Rabbitmq logs the following cryptic error message.  Anyone have any idea what this might mean?

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 15-Feb-2011::18:36:41 ===
error on TCP connection <0.12966.102>:{ssl_upgrade_failure,
                                       {{function_clause,
                                         [{ssl_alert,description_txt,")"},
                                          {ssl_alert,alert_txt,1},
                                          {ssl_connection,log_alert,3},
                                          {ssl_connection,handle_event,3},
                                          {gen_fsm,handle_msg,7},
                                          {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]},
                                        {gen_fsm,sync_send_all_state_event,
                                         [<0.12967.102>,started,5000]}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to upgrade to the later version of erlang and rabbitmq.